# Value of type 'CartCell' has no member 'navigationController' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to go back from current page to previous page by clicking on the cell. Basically i am using the swipe to delete and after swipe to delete i checking the condition if the price is 0 then go back to previous page but in the cell it is showing me an error "Value of type 'CartCell' has no member 'navigationController'"

```
extension CartCell : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            if isPlacedOrder {return}
            let row = tableView.tag % 1000
            let section = tableView.tag / 1000
            arrayGlobleCart[section].restItems.remove(at: row)
            (self.superview as? UITableView)?.beginUpdates()
            (self.superview as? UITableView)?.endUpdates()
            GFunctions.shared.APICallSaveCart { (_) in }
                self.updatePrice!(true)
            self.updatePrice = { isUpdate in
                if arrayGlobleCart.count == 0{
                    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)// Here i am checking if the price is 0.0 then go back but in this line it is showing me an error "Value of type 'CartCell' has no member 'navigationController'"
                }
            }
            self.tblItem.reloadData()
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {}
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.navigationController` That'd work if `self` is a `UIViewController` with a NavigationController, but here you are inside the `CartCell` which I guess is a `UICollectionViewCell` or a `UITableViewCell`, so it' won't do. Instead, you need to tell the ViewController (with a custom delegate, or a custom closure) to pop.

Comment: @Larme ok, then how to do by custom delegate or custom closure? Because i am a beginner in swift.

Comment: What is CartCell exactly? Is there some ViewController that's linked to it? That manage that view/cell?

Comment: @Larme cartcell is a UITableViewCell and it is view controller which manage cell

Comment: Then, in CartCell, add: `var onGlobalCartDidEmptied: (() -> Void)?`, instead of  `_ = self.navigationController` here, do self.onGlobalCartDidEmptied?()` and in cellForRowAtIndexPath where you configure the CartCell: `cell.onGlobalCartDidEmptied = { [weak self] in self?.navigationController?.popView... }`

Comment: @Larme it is not working after adding `cell.onGlobalCartDidEmptied = { [weak self] in self?.navigationController?.popView... }` it's showing same error. And where do i put `self.onGlobalCartDidEmptied?()` ?